# Time Complexity - Refactor O(N²) to O(N)

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, big-o, time-complexity

I have a function here which calculates the number of unique integer pairs in an array, who's sum is even. Currently I've coded this using a nested loop however this is inefficient as a nested loop results in a time complexity of `O(N²)`.

In this example, `A` represents the array, `P` and `Q` represent the integer pair. `Q` should always be greater than `P` as otherwise this results in non-unique integer pairs *(where P and Q can point to the same value in the array)*.

```
public int GetEvenSumCount(int[] A)
{
    // result storage
    int result = 0;

    // loop through each array element to get P
    for (int P = 0; P < A.Length; P++)
    {
        // loop through each array element to get Q
        for (int Q = P + 1; Q < A.Length; Q++)
        {
            // calculate whether A[P] + A[Q] is even.
            if ((A[P] + A[Q]) % 2 == 0)
            {
                result++;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

I now need to refactor this so that the worse case time complexity is `O(N)` but I haven't a clue where to start! I know this will involve using only one loop, rather than a nested loop, but I don't know how you would sum `A[P]` with `A[Q]` in this respect.

Comment: Clearly you can't do it by explicitly visiting every pair. But you don't have to. Will report back with solution.

Comment: This wouldn't, by any chance, be an interview question for Twitter, would it?

Comment: @templatetypedef, It is an interview question, but not for twitter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can obtain an even sum in two ways:

1. Add two even value, like `2 + 4 = 6`
2. Add two odd value, like `1 + 3 = 4`

On the contrary, adding an even value with an odd value will always be odd, like `1 + 2 = 3`

So the total number of even sums you can get is:

1. The number of pair of even values
2. Plus, the number of pair of odd values

The number of pairs you have in a collection of `n` item is:

```
N = n * (n-1) / 2
```

Full code:

```
static bool IsEven(int i)
{
    return i % 2 == 0;
}

static bool IsOdd(int i)
{
    return i % 2 != 0;
}

static int GetPairCount(int n)
{
    return n * (n- 1) / 2;
}

public static int GetEvenSumCount(int[] A)
{
    int evensCount = A.Count(IsEven);
    int oddCount = A.Count(IsOdd);

    return GetPairCount(evensCount) + GetPairCount(oddCount);
}
```

As you can see, there is no nested loop and you don't need to actually compute the sums.

The complexity of this implementation is O(N).

Answer (score 2):

The sum of two integers can be even only if either both are odd or both are even.

Scan the array, and count the number of odd and even numbers. Lets say these are N1 and N2.

```
The number of pairs = (N1 Choose 2) + (N2 Choose 2).
                    = N1*(N1-1)/2 + N2*(N2-1)/2
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it helped a lot! Could you explain why you do: N1*(N1-1)/2 + N2*(N2-1)/2 ? I know it works, but I don't understand what this is doing?

Comment: It is the number of ways in which you can choose 2 items out of n items, without order being important. C(n,2). To get more information you can google for permutations and combinations, or visit this link http://www.mathsisfun.com/combinatorics/combinations-permutations.html

Answer (score 1):

As promised, reporting back with solution:

```
static int GetEvenSumCountFast(int[] A)
{
    int[] OddEven = new int[2];
    for (int i = 0; i < A.Length; i++)
        OddEven[A[i] & 1]++;
    return OddEven[0] * (OddEven[0] - 1) / 2 +
        OddEven[1] * (OddEven[1] - 1) / 2;
}
```

Well the other guys already solved it but whatever..

Alternative:

```
static int GetEvenSumCountFast(int[] A)
{
    int odd = 0, even = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < A.Length; i++)
    {
        odd += A[i] & 1;
        even += ~A[i] & 1;
    }
    return odd * (odd - 1) / 2 +
        even * (even - 1) / 2;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I notice that you have a "fast" example. Is this faster than O(N) time complexity?

Comment: No, they're both O(N) - "fast" because they're faster than O(N^2). You can't do it in less than O(N), at worst you'd have to look at all the input.

Answer (score 1):

As the sum of two even numbers is even and the sum of two odd numbers is, too (but the numbers of an odd and an even number is odd) I would first group them into even and odd numbers:

```
var grouped = A.GroupBy(x => x % 2 == 0);
```

Now the number of unique pairs in each group with n being the number of elements is:

```
(n-1) + (n-2) + … + 1 = n * (n-1) / 2
```

So (independent if we are in the even or odd group):

```
return gouped.Sum(x => {var n = x.Count(); return n * (n-1) / 2; });
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all those who have contributed to this question, I have taken all of your notes here and produced a concise function which behaves as expected, and still conforms to the required O(N) time complexity

```
public int GetEvenSumCount(int[] A)
{
    int odd = A.Count(o => o % 2 != 0);
    int even = N.Length - odd;
    return odd * (odd - 1) / 2 + even * (even - 1) / 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The question was to find unique even sums...in all of the above solutions...when counting the number of odd and even no.s they are not taking account of their uniqueness.For example if there are two even numbers having same value say 4 and another even number 6.There will be two even sums having value 10 and they are non unique

Comment: I see your point, but that "might" not matter. Besides it was an interview question and the answers above were still wrong! :-P

Comment: P.S. there would actually be four even sums having the value 10, not two...why? 1st 4 and 1st 6, 1st 4 and 2nd 6, 2nd 4 and 1st 6, 2nd 4 and 2nd 6 :-)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've got a solution that is O (n). Kind of. You could consider it cheating. It probably is.

"int" has limited range - +/- 2^31.

We must assume the possible array size is unlimited - otherwise O () notation doesn't make sense. If array size was limited to say 2^64 elements, then the problem could always be solved in constant time O (1) using 2^128 operations...

So create a bitmap of all possible 2^32 int values contained in the array. That takes O (n) steps. Create a new array from the bitmap with all duplicates removed. That array has at most min (n, 2^32) entries. The rest can always be done in 2^64 operations, which is O (1). So the total is O (n), but with a *huge* constant factor if n is around 2^32.

If the array contained bytes and not ints, this would actually be a reasonably fast algorithm.

Now finding an efficient algorithm, that seems kind of tough.